# How to work with data: Any of type java.util.Arrays.ArrayList?

Tags: scala, casting

Using the AWT.Transferable, I get an argument "data: Any" which is actually of type java.util.Arrays.ArrayList. How can I cast the "data" explicitly to this type?
It seems I do not have any access to the "ArrayList"-Type itself...

Comment: IIRC ArrayList in Java are always untyped (i.e ArrayList<Object> or ArrayList[Any] in Scala), you have to cast each element individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
data match {
  case jlist: java.util.List[_] => // I got an java.util.list!
  case _ => // oops, unexpected!
}
```

is type-safe, which doesn't happen to be the case of `asInstanceOf`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the class explicitly? Couldn't you use the `java.util.List` interface?

```
data.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[_]]
```

Note that casting is not encouraged, which is why it looks so awful in Scala!

Comment: Ah, that did the trick. Should just have checked the interfaces of ArrayList... Thanks!